# Unable to use ACompat v7 below version 20

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-sdk-tools

I am not sure when this problem actually started.
But today when i tried to create a project with following settings it gives  error

My IDE is Eclipse with ADT Plugin

min sdk 8 , target SDK 19 ,  Compile-with  19
sdk tools 23.0.5
sdk platform tools  21
sdk build tools 21.1

the project was created , but it shows a lot of  errors
when i change the the target and compile-with to 20 all errors are gone.
( I also need to delete the support-v4 library that is added to projects automatically as it is a different version than the one in the appcompat-v7 )

Any help is fixing this mess would be really helpful.

So far i tried updating the sdk tools using using sdk manager , it only made things worse , so i went back to the older version .

So Now i have everything updated in my sdk manager, even the system-images. I noticed that when i  try to create a new project , even though the sdk manager shows i have 5.0.1, i can only create projects upto API-21 4.x L Preview,  is this normal or related to my issue.

Comment: You should always target the highest available SDK, why would you use lower ones?

Comment: @Chris K. I know , but i am trying to modify a previously existing project, and this setup is for testing some features.

Comment: I am leaving this comment to say that i accomplished what i wanted only by setting up a seperate older copy of ADT-Bundle which we had backed up earlier. So i still dont know what the problem is, even though i got what i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested on my environment

```
min sdk 8, target sdk 19, compile with 19, sdk tool 24.0.2, platform tool 21, build tool 21.1.2
```

After delete the duplicated android-support-v4.jar, every works fine. The project can get compiled and run without any problem.

Did you update your appcompat-v7 to the latest version? In my settings

```
Android support repository 10, Android support library 21.0.3
```

Comment: I dont have access to that environment right now, but once i do, i will check and get back.

Comment: So i checked, my sdk manager says support repository is 10 and support library is 21.0.3. I will update the sdk-tools to 24.0.2 check and get back.

Comment: @user699617 with Android support repository 10 and support library 21.0.3, you still got the same problems?

Comment: yes , same issues , i just updated the sdk-tools to 24.0.2 , still it shows the same errors. The errors say something related to appcompat_v7  missing values-21 folder

Comment: @user699617 delete the appcompat_v7 project you previously created, then create an android project with any name, a new appcompat_v7 will automatically created for you. try set this new appcompat_v7 project as a dependency of your other android project.

Comment: ok i tried as u said, in a new workspace even, it created a new appcompat v7 , but now even that shows errors, then on a whim  i checked the compiled with on that and it was 19 , so when i changed it to 20 and cleaned the errors are gone. , i still had   to set my project to 20 before it got fixed.

Comment: The last suggestion i can give to you is to use an old version of appcompat_v7 which located in $ANROID_SDK/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7 if you insist on an old android build target in your project. Just unzip the *.aar file, e.g. appcompat-v7-18.0.0.aar and integrate all the unzip file to an Eclipse android project.

Comment: I had to use a old release of adt-bundle. The problem still exists, not sure why.